# Duplicate results after deleting a row

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

In sqflite v2.2.7 my query is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT sets.id, sets.workout, sets.weight, sets.target_num_time, workouts.name, sets.created_at, evaluations.type, evaluations.elapsed_time FROM sets, workouts, evaluations WHERE SUBSTRING(sets.created_at, 0, 10) = ? AND sets.workout = workouts.id AND evaluations.set_id = sets.id ORDER BY sets.created_at DESC', [today]
```

It works but when I delete a row it returns duplicates while the database has no duplicate rows:

```
static void deleteSet(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM sets WHERE id = ? ', [id]);
}
```

```
[
    {id: 132, workout: 7, weight: 105, target_num_time: 10, created_at: 2023-06-22T20:12:03.557892, type: clear, elapsed_time: 02:39}
    {id: 132, workout: 7, weight: 105, target_num_time: 10,  created_at: 2023-06-22T20:12:03.557892, type: clear, elapsed_time: 00:00}
    {id: 132, workout: 7, weight: 105, target_num_time: 10,  created_at: 2023-06-22T20:12:03.557892, type: clear, elapsed_time: 00:02}
    {id: 132, workout: 7, weight: 105, target_num_time: 10,  created_at: 2023-06-22T20:12:03.557892, type: clear, elapsed_time: 00:01}
    {id: 131, workout: 7, weight: 10, target_num_time: 1,  created_at: 2023-06-22T20:11:47.465075, type: clear, elapsed_time: 00:00}
]
```

You can see identical `id` number and `created_at` values. It only happens after I delete a row. I tried updating sqflite and to use keyword `DISTINCT`.